# Animating particles with collision avoidance?

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I need to drive a large number of small 2D cars around on screen in a fairly random fashion... I have the Trapcode Suite.  I'd really like them not to overlap each other.  What's the easiest way to achieve this? Any good tricks using C4Dlite maybe? At the moment I'm using Particular to splatter them all over the screen, and it looks a bit rubbish.

Comment: Don't know about C4D, but there is a physics plugin for After Effects called Newton 2 that can achieve that.

Comment: You can do it with expressions, there is a sampleImage function which you could call for perimeter points on each car to find out if they're overlapping, https://is.gd/cXC6Il You could also just fudge it by avoiding cars within a certain radius. But it would be super slow for lots of cars. If it was my project I'd do it with a script, using something like the Boids flocking algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the built in [Foam particle render](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/simulation-effects.html#foam_effect) - it does have basic collision avoidance

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with the enable flocking option
attract 0%
separate 20%

Comment: In Trapcode Particular?